# Bad class design using Java Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, runnable

Could you please explain why in the following program implementing the Runnable interface in this way is a bad design decision? Intuitively, if I had to write this myself, I would make Hotel its own class and write a specification for run() in a new class that implements Runnable. However, I can't really explain why the below code is a bad design decision.

The class models a hotel with a waiting queue of people and a list of rooms. There are several "desks" which run on separate threads, each desk is responsible for removing people from the queue and checking them into available rooms. Check-out is not included for simplicity. The implementation of the methods doesn't matter (trust that it's thread-safe), this question is about the design decision of putting run() into the Hotel class.

```
public class Hotel implements Runnable {
    private final static int NR_ROOMS = 10;
    private final Person [] rooms = new Person [ NR_ROOMS ];
    private final List < Person > queue = new ArrayList < >();
    private final Lock queueLock = new ReentrantLock ();

    private boolean occupied (int i) {
        return ( rooms [i] != null);
    }

    private int checkIn ( Person p) {
        // add Person to a free room
    }


    private void enter ( Person p) {
        // add a person to the waiting queue
    }

    // every desk employee should run as a separate thread
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // remove guests from the queue and check them in
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible code example. I can't know what is bad about the code if you comment out all the methods. Also, I don't know main class that adds this runnable as a thread.

Comment: Mixing up a data class, business logic, and multithreading in one place can't be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of OO programming is to create classes that model your business logic; as your problem has a hotel, rooms, persons, etc., one could expect there to be classes to represent these 'nouns' in your problem domain. Methods on those classes then represent actions performed with the objects.

The immediate problem I have with a `run()` method on the Hotel class is that isn't at all clear what it means for a hotel to "run". I suppose it might make sense in some cases; if you had a simulation, for instance, and there were rules set up about what was supposed to happen over time at the hotel. The unnatural part of that is that a hotel is normally a place to which things happen, as opposed to one that does things.

For that matter, it seems oversimplified to me that an instance of hotel has a list of `rooms`, each of which is of type `Person`. You can make simple logic work this way, but one of the principles of OO design is to make it easy to extend an existing program because you have modeled the real-world object of the problem domain, and therefore doing more things with them will be naturally easier than if you had not. In this case, It seems to me to match the known problem space much better if the Hotel has a list of Room objects, and then each Room object can contain some number of Person objects. Then the number of Persons in a room is more flexible, could be different for different rooms, etc.

I'm all for starting with a simple system, but since you're asking about OO design, I thought I'd take the opportunity to point these things out about this one.